# Heteropalindromes in a Word Square

Tags: no-computers, word-square

Say hello to a not-so-simple, 4x4 word square:

[image: Screenshot of the word square.]

This little monstrosity has two rules; to define the first rule, have you ever heard of a [heteropalindrome](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03201691.pdf)?

> *Strings of letters that form words when read both forward and backward (e.g., "deliver" and "reviled") are termed heteropalindromes.*

Now you have, and with that out of the way; the first rule is that the result for each row and column, must be classified as a heteropalindrome, as described above. For example:

```
[s, a, g, a]
[p,  ,  ,  ]
[a,  ,  ,  ]
[s,  ,  ,  ]
```

The second rule is simply that words must be contained in [YAWL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elasticdog/yawl/master/yawl-0.3.2.03/word.list).

Your task is simple, complete the word square, while meeting the aforementioned constraints. The *first* answer meeting the aforementioned requirements will get the checkmark.

Comment: Are repeated words okay?

Comment: @Deusovi yes, they are.

Comment: are true palindromes allowed?

Comment: @SteveV of course :) since repeated words are okay.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution meeting your requirements:

> `[W, A, R, D]`
>  `[A, J, A, R]`
>  `[R, A, J, A]`
>  `[D, R, A, W]`

Answer (score 11):

Yet another one, with all 16 words different: (I admit that this is a computer-assisted answer, in the sense that I wrote a program to extract the list of 4-letter heteropalindromes from YAWL. I constructed the square manually from that list.)

> ```
> alan
> rima
> even
> sena
> ```

For side information: there are only 16 unique such squares containing 16 unique words (not counting rotations and reflections of same grids), which can be verified via [this script](https://tio.run/##nVjbctw2En3XV8ybpY2zZc3o4lKVv0SrSoEkZoQQJCAAFDPJ@tu9jT4HY8dWpGT9MBAvfTt9@kLHY3kM8@7LlzWkIW8@bf54Z2Yzv3u/eZf7JdXTxDDodXRjPYfwmOvZuxLqGc2s13NwXp@b3ur7xa6UU32dS6rHPDs9i7V6RmtV7mBSV09vF71/mM0K/avq70xS@8m4os9d0rO4yOc@w67R@9nCnxKCno8Gfg8O14OFH3NITt83B1NPOzmNO69mUn@LVTnjJ32eH43KTQZ28xpgbw7qry2u1@ujJW5G9Y3OJvpPv3rIP4YAf2dD/xF3slGvHeyuFvEVM2biAz@JXxdWPi@Mk/gm4LHaCfeJQzndB44SR4TcswE@8HcKQU8xp3GZZDQPpjN6faS@kf7sk9E8lqUDnjPw8wE4zQv8y8xvnpaD6rHgx0D5XOBPMYgvOcjNzPdAvxLzMFJu5bWEZ4iXI64ReIQD8tf4siDP9FPyjvdCAK8S8j3YI3BfwHezIA@1cpj/AX4aD5ygdwjAN5Hvgqte@@U3rZNhwfvZJvjrBr3f0c6QwCuhRSEuwEeAYP2MwB/3Owu57FF/JdEv8mIy4F00PjIve8b7SN5m@jmBzyazjgvzhdMjPy456gUOq5kV3xTCRP6wHsHnSD9sD1w931uD34M/lvVEHkSrPNuzjs0ctJ/YBDxLYp9Z/AKeIv@F/kufUjwD67Ij/7wBz22rq8B6dgl5D3jv2Oo8mgPwThF6PHmKfiF5mNHHIHdI7B@TJw8bb6NBPnJBvSH/R@KXLeS8Y303fBl/YZ1L/av8SFxzH9gPmf@C@5NlvAH9zhb4mT3sFON76KUceSr10oF/9ggcU@MreMx@XVb4ETgX9h71ZQv7mUUdStpwGpyHxbf3V9QN6lx4VNA3mG/2YxHz5LUlHogng6979qtiW7@YOIeAo@Ep9bMyz9oXpgV1J3gcOGeUhzkM7MfEa3YH9iPgyf4q7QN9gHlPFnNS6Mg8IC/hAPzyvGDOGeRD@s0ReWJfMIjXJfB85XwdLOR96ALuwz9PPGPjTzTEE37ZBN6LGPFDv80GdTEYzNsY5hFxPVv2NfRrOzF/qPffyePeI@@J9yUt6CvBs/9Cn7jJ@kRfyCv4lGfbYa5y34jAyXTsLwHxTpz7wmvo@5V5lIEOe/CzT9AjeWn1@jvqDfgd2lyw4JEnX6Rvgm/PyPOR@8YhsM4TeDFb4DKSX8IXfW7HU19n33XMoyXfkO/E/SKzXkb2B@EDcOF8Md7tYQ/5kbQT19b/cL9jviTOmXNtYF1wTk1tDgzkB3CNyHe3JM5BnAfOQzMBh8h4CudPYr31NpJXh4B@wH7rfMMdpwFvCudnJF6Z9ezJd9HPOTRbzknsZwvPhPqQ@3vUa2HfQFye/U/2NtU30Y/I/UD0I@7RBbwP/CfT5tzIOkDeE3ETXkTwAPyxvy3I@9LsIo6SwcfS6om8sdxDYzjtr9g36a@MH9XnOF8H7qvS5gzr00Ev9wchPt5r8XHOsN8L3Jl9hHs1nsseMXJ/YN9Cv1vpT2@wpxXb@h7m8dzmgHfgqWU/lYYLfajnzi@cE5x3Q@B@xzpw7GPka@FcGxhXx755tGvbv9oc5J6BOXQgj/KI@wP9LIxTcIq0iz2wxU980tIzr6xH7tWHtHCOLzPjJ0/x/SP7XGZ/mcjvI0/0jYF7UcQeJn2t1VfbCw@MV89H6p@4T9sEvIIbuZegPgvjS8R5SK7hvLI/Yv6SB4X@xa97psYjbSehPljPzMPAPbG0OfkYuE85zofY9gh8J9DObE/2IvdW9Kln8DeHx0C5ifO99esj9paFfMVek3v63fpPgh6pX@RjXAz3RHwPsN/HtudM3P/Yzz334Yl8H1hvI78b5DuLc5j@c94OjOfAPbRjXkbyeLRtflj2V@zPrvHRQm7kd@BAXgn@rIdAvs/tu1GfC1ztuxV5tsAntX3YoR9Ezm3DeTAa7i3RcH8WvZ/PzvYpTJs@eG/7IqWXN26qI3Iz2L1ZfBlcX870a/@X7vhLZ6V9yGf/Nw/PZWG7ONuHtOk38uyP9f7Dw6ZervVSJT/fbf6s4b5/qP93sH733sbtN1X806f@83c2t28Zvdu@aXX7qllR8ILd3Zt2d2/a3b1udwe7/VzkpQ9n@WmpKZO/7x/U0np5krg728i//aVqu3wvj@7v7n6@fPiM@/Xl7enlr2jLax8eHjY/iyQ06NsVUlH1X1G1FVXbb1Wd1O1eUre9v4S67Vd1KlHREr1V5U5U7r5XeVJ79aPabXXz8uEnkaL23Z@1q/BVtbBTC1di4eolCycr1y9a2d5vxcqV/KqVqx@tqILraulKLV2Lpeu/snSydvOjtV2Naasx1d/rZvP6ZZuq6qbavVa7N2L35jW7J9u3L9re3u800vp7I79q@@avbau622r/Ru3fiv3bt@zXf@tHEZJQdxrqTkOtv7fy@6pgrYCPXwtC3Lt93b36Lz/V4lD@V5bV7Nw@vCm1Nz2q6nvJ96KrFkDlU0X848PfVfaTaMtPAEjzIJ5JLPrwn@i4T9/oSFVFfvo/FCouk5vP9f2LN98X8EVExgwsatu5a3/828Ro5@E8P12cxeTmcu7tfM6HF@iB8E4Wi2KH0yPkDyL/yk/vN9nGT@/@U2ez6Kt/yd8XX778Dw).

There are 2720 unique squares in total if duplicate words and palindromes are allowed. Notably, under this rule, there are a few very trivial answers due to the property of certain words like

> ```
> anan
> nana
> anan
> nana
>
> abba
> boob
> boob
> abba
>
> anna
> naan
> naan
> anna
> ```

Finally, there is exactly one grid that manages to have one diagonal also being a heteropalindrome and the other diagonal containing vowels and being a palindrome (but unfortunately not a word in YAWL):

> ```
> eses
> slee
> eels
> sese
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Deuosvi had already posted an answer, but I couldn't stop myself when I found another one:

> `[P, E, T, S]`
>  `[E, D, I, T]`
>  `[T, I, D, E]`
>  `[S, T, E, P]`